# Is there PyPDF2 method for determining if text read from a PDF is bold?

Tags: python, pdf, text, pypdf

I'm doing some web scraping of glossaries and dictionaries for an online vocabulary and some of the information I'm trying to acquire are in PDF format.  I'm using PyPDF2 to read the text from the PDF into string with the goal of classifying the information into either a 2 column (Terms , Definitions) Pandas DataFrame.  Since there isn't a common delimiter to split the text on, I was wondering if it's possible to split the text on **bold** text.  Splitting on '\n' isn't an option as the PDFreader tends to insert '\n' at random.

Here's a sample of the glossary:

**contaminant** — A substance emitted into the air.

**contaminant code** — A contaminant’s five-digit identifying code. A list is available at the
EAS Web page: .

**control device** — See abatement device.

The code I've got so far is:

```
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
print(reader.numPages)

num_pages = reader.numPages
count = 0
text =""

while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = reader.getPage(count)
    count += 1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
```

Comment: There is no such function in PyPDF2. It looks like you have to walk the walk and extract each page's objects, find the content stream, and then parse it manually. A tall task – as you noticed, PyPDF2 already has problems finding the plain unformatted text. (It's worth keeping in mind that it is not a fact one can *always* extract *all* content *exactly* from *any* PDF.)

Comment: .. That said, if this is all, you might as well extract the text as-is and add bold around the first phrase up to (and excluding) the first em dash.